# Payara6 - Hazelcast error can't running payara

Tags: hosting, hazelcast, payara

I install the payara 6 on the ubuntu server 20.04 on a2hosting cloud, and when i try to run the payara I got the hazelcast error, when i tried to contact the payara team they inform me that issue is related to the hazelcast, please your advice.

I re-install the payara 5 and everything are works fine.

Payara 6 with hazelcast error:

```
[#|2022-11-06T15:49:29.772+0000|SEVERE|Payara 6.2022.1|com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1667749767342;_TimeMillis=1667749769772;_LevelValue=1000;|
  [216.137.185.19]:4900 [development] [5.1.1] inetAddress can't be null
java.lang.NullPointerException: inetAddress can't be null
at com.hazelcast.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:59)
at com.hazelcast.cluster.Address.<init>(Address.java:73)
at com.hazelcast.cluster.Address.<init>(Address.java:57)
at fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.DomainDiscoveryService.discoverNodes(DomainDiscoveryService.java:176)
at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner.getPossibleAddresses(DiscoveryJoiner.java:72)
at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner.getPossibleAddressesForInitialJoin(DiscoveryJoiner.java:61)
at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.joinViaPossibleMembers(TcpIpJoiner.java:141)
at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.doJoin(TcpIpJoiner.java:100)
at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:139)
at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node.join(Node.java:826)
at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node.start(Node.java:484)
at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:124)
at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:217)
at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:196)
at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:134)
at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:61)
at fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore.bootstrapHazelcast(HazelcastCore.java:550)
at fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore.getInstance(HazelcastCore.java:242)
at fish.payara.nucleus.config.ClusteredConfig.postConstruct(ClusteredConfig.java:100)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:466)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2103)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:690)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:55)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:188)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:211)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:334)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:466)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2103)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
|#]

[#|2022-11-06T15:49:29.773+0000|SEVERE|Payara 6.2022.1|com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1667749767342;_TimeMillis=1667749769773;_LevelValue=1000;|
  [216.137.185.19]:4900 [development] [5.1.1] Could not join cluster. Shutting down now!|#]

[#|2022-11-06T15:49:29.775+0000|WARNING|Payara 6.2022.1|com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1667749767342;_TimeMillis=1667749769775;_LevelValue=900;|
  [216.137.185.19]:4900 [development] [5.1.1] Terminating forcefully...|#]

[#|2022-11-06T15:49:29.789+0000|WARNING|Payara 6.2022.1|com.hazelcast.internal.util.phonehome.PhoneHome|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1667749767342;_TimeMillis=1667749769789;_LevelValue=900;|
  [216.137.185.19]:4900 [development] [5.1.1] Could not schedule phone home task! Most probably Hazelcast failed to start.|#]

[#|2022-11-06T15:49:29.791+0000|INFO|Payara 6.2022.1|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1667749767342;_TimeMillis=1667749769791;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00015;|
  Shutdown requested
```

.................................
.................................

Comment: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/6034

Answer (score 0):

It's probably this issue: https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/5193

It's already fixed in the Payara 5 patch release, but not yet fixed in Payara 6.

#### Details

This is not a Hazelcast issue, it comes from Payara's implementation of Hazelcast `DiscoveryService`. The implementation tries to use `null` as the `InetAddress` value when constructing a `com.hazelcast.cluster.Address` object ([DomainDiscoveryService.java#L176](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/payara-server-6.2022.1/nucleus/payara-modules/hazelcast-bootstrap/src/main/java/fish/payara/nucleus/hazelcast/DomainDiscoveryService.java#L176))

The `null` is returned from Payara's [`MemberAddressPicker.findMyAddress()`](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/payara-server-6.2022.1/nucleus/payara-modules/hazelcast-bootstrap/src/main/java/fish/payara/nucleus/hazelcast/MemberAddressPicker.java#L183-L222) method which filters out several types of network interfaces (e.g. loopback, docker0, ...). This will probably be the case in your environment.

The fix in the Pull request [5193](https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/5193) just uses the localhost address when no other is found.

Answer (score 0):

In the new payara version, the issue is fixed